# transform columns that start by the same name into one column split in rows by years

Tags: r

## Specific case

How can I go from the first image below to the following one. The difference is that the second image contains a column named Year that is filled up with the last four digits of the columns that start by "Operating". I want to keep the name of the column, use the years as a separate variable and list all the values of the operating columns in one column.

### Current

[image]

### Goal

[image]

### Data

```r
data <- data.frame(
  "Registered number" = c("03600726", "13243384", "09884706", "09884706", "03600726", "03600726", "13243384", "13243384"),
  "Primary UK SIC (2007) code" = c(46719, 64191, 35140, 35140, 46719, 46719, 64191, 64191),
  "Number of employees Last avail. yr" = c(249, 198, 91, 91, 249, 249, 198, 198),
  "Year" = c(2023, 2023, 2022, 2021, 2022, 2021, 2022, 2021),
  "Operating Profit th GBP" = c(2023, 2023, -5000, 11000, 153021, -14397, 5, NA)
)
```

### Attempt

```
data_long <- pivot_longer(data, 
                           cols = starts_with("202"), 
                           names_to = c(".value", "Year"), 
                           names_pattern = "(\\d{4})_(.*)", 
                           values_drop_na = TRUE)


data_long$"Operating Profit th GBP" <- gsub(",", "", as.character(data_long$"Operating Profit th GBP"))
```

## General case

The general case would be from

### Current

[image]

### Goal

[image]

current data

```
    data <- data.frame(
  "Registered number" = c("09884706", "03600726", "13243384"),
  "Primary UK SIC (2007) code" = c(35140, 46719, 64191),
  "Number of employees Last avail. yr" = c(91, 249, 198),
  "Operating Profit th GBP 2023" = c("n.a.", "n.a.", "313,417"),
  "Operating Profit th GBP 2022" = c("-5,000", "153,021", "5"),
  "Operating Profit th GBP 2021" = c("11,000", "-14,397", "n.a."),
  "Net Interest th GBP 2023" = c("n.a.", "n.a.", "-313,227"),
  "Net Interest th GBP 2022" = c("-4,000", "-776", "n.a."),
  "Net Interest th GBP 2021" = c("-4,000", "1,449", "n.a.")
)
```

goal general case

```
data <- data.frame(
  "Registered number" = c("09884706", "03600726", "13243384", "09884706", "03600726", "13243384", "09884706", "03600726", "13243384"),
  "Primary UK SIC (2007) code" = c(35140, 46719, 64191, 35140, 46719, 64191, 35140, 46719, 64191),
  "Number of employees Last avail. yr" = c(91, 249, 198, 91, 249, 198, 91, 249, 198),
  "Year" = c(2023, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2021, 2021),
  "Operating Profit th GBP" = c("n.a.", "n.a.", "313,417", "-5,000", "153,021", "5", "11,000", "-14,397", "n.a."),
  "Net Interest th GBP" = c("n.a.", "n.a.", "-313,227", "-4,000", "-776", "0", "-4,000", "1,449", "n.a.")
)
```

what I would like is a code that I can use regardless the number of columns with different names. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The data you have provided does not match the current situation displayed.

Comment: Are you looking for the reverse?

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT TO ANSWER THE NEW GENERAL CASE]**

**Please note** that I had to change `data <- data.frame(...)` to `data <- tibble(..)` from your provided data, or it would not work.

You still have to manually provide the pattern for `vector_columns`, it can be done automatically but is it necessary in your use case ?

```r
# In the general case of format "variable year", in a modular way

vector_columns <- c("Operating Profit th GBP","Net Interest th GBP")
regex_columns <- paste(vector_columns, collapse = "|")
year_regex <- "\\d{4}"

data |> 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with(vector_columns),
    names_pattern = paste0("(",regex_columns,") (",year_regex,")"), 
    names_to = c(".value", "Year")
  ) 

# names_pattern will look like this : "(var1|var2) (\\d{4})" which is a regex that can be adapted for any kind of repeating pattern
```

---

**[OLD ANSWER]**

Look into the function `pivot_longer` https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html

You gave the wrong data in your post (what you want instead of what you have), so I made up data usings the `billboard` dataset instead, which form is similar to your data. Replace `billboard` with your data.frame and let me know if it works.

```r
data(billboard)

# Copy your format, no need to use this part
billboard <- billboard |> 
    rename("Registered number" = "artist",
         "Primary UK SIC (2007) code" = "track",
         "Number of employees Last avail. yr" = "date.entered",
         "Operating Profit th GBP 2023" = "wk1",
         "Operating Profit th GBP 2022" = "wk2",
         "Operating Profit th GBP 2021" = "wk3") |> 
  select("Registered number", "Primary UK SIC (2007) code","Number of employees Last avail. yr",
         "Operating Profit th GBP 2023","Operating Profit th GBP 2022",
         "Operating Profit th GBP 2021")


# Insert your data here
billboard |> 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("Operating Profit th GBP"),
    names_to = "Year",
    names_prefix = "Operating Profit th GBP ",
    values_to = "Operating Profit th GBP",
    values_drop_na = FALSE
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have a generic example? I mean, if there where more columns like "Operating profit" but with different names.

Comment: I would need an exemple of initial and goal data to help you !

Comment: Thanks! I have uploaded the question to include a more general case.

Comment: Happy it helped you, please edit your first question so that it's easier for new readers to see if they need the same answer as you did ! And don't hesitate to accept the answer so that it is more visible